# Why does calling mmap() with large size not fail?

Tags: c++, c, linux, memory-management, mmap

I try to use `mmap()` to manipulate virtual memory. I want to reserve and commit a region of memory. I tested this code:

```
const unsigned long gygabyte = 1024 * 1024 * 1024;
const unsigned long gygabyteCount = 2;
const unsigned long maxCapacity = gygabyteCount * gygabyte;

int main()
{
    char* pMemory;

    pMemory = (char*)mmap(NULL, maxCapacity, PROT_NONE, MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
    if ( mprotect(pMemory, maxCapacity, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE) != 0 )
    {
        cout << "Memory Allocation has failed" << endl;
    }
    usleep(-1);

    return 0;
}
```

I ran several copies of my program (say 6) from a terminal. I didn't ever see "Memory Allocation has failed" in any one. I'm running on 64-bit Ubuntu with 4GB RAM. Can anyone tell me something about this?

Comment: The code you post doesn't commit anything. Try walking through those memory regions.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`mmap` reserves a region of the process's virtual address space, but does not immediately allocate physical RAM for it. Therefore, on a 64-bit platform, you can reserve a vast amount without failure (although you still need to check for failure; your example code doesn't). Physical pages of RAM are allocated later when the memory is accessed.

`mprotect` just changes the read/write access of the reserved memory; it won't make it resident in RAM either. You would get the same effect by passing `PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE` instead of `PROT_NONE` to `mmap`, and removing the call to `mprotect`.

If you need the memory to be resident in RAM straight away, then use `mlock` for that. It will fail if there isn't enough RAM available. On many linux platforms (including Ubuntu), there is a resource limit (`RLIMIT_MEMLOCK`) which restricts how much memory any process can lock; you can adjust this with `ulimit -l`.

Comment: Must it look like this? `pMemory = (char*)mmap(NULL, maxCapacity, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0); mlock(pMemory, maxCapacity)` I think the memory used in mlock() is not the memory reserved by mmap().

Comment: I tried to reserve 1GB and commit them by this way. But mlock() returned -1.

Comment: @user1173593: Check the value of `errno` afterwards. It might well be `EPERM`, indicating that your resource limit is too low (you can set it with `ulimit -l`, but there's probably a hard limit as well), or perhaps `ENOMEM`, indicating that there's not enough memory, or other errors documented in the manpage.

Answer (score 1):

mmap is useful for preparing a mapping of the memory you ask for, but it does not allocate it to your program. The kernel takes care of allocating the memory when you access it, thus `mmap`-ing 8 GB is possible on a 4GB memory, if you do not access those  8GB simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

You should first check the result of `mmap`. In case it returns `MAP_FAILED`, it means the allocation has failed. The kernel wouldn't actually allocate so much memory at once, but would rather map physical or swapped space on-demand when you access the corresponding regions of that block.

In your particular case you don't need a separate call to `mprotect`, since passing these flags for the entire region can be made at the time of calling `mmap`:

```
pMemory = mmap(NULL, maxCapacity,
    PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);

if (pMemory == MAP_FAILED) {
    /* allocation failed */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to tell Linux you want it to do commit accounting:

```
echo "2" > /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory
```

Otherwise it keeps the legacy default (from when Linux was a toy OS) of allowing unlimited overcommit and making your apps horribly crash when they run out of physical memory.

Also, as others have said, you need to check the return value of `mmap` against `MAP_FAILED`, and there's no need to use `mprotect`. Simply pass the right values of `PROT_*` to `mmap` to begin with.