# How does Linux implement optimistic memory allocation?

Tags: linux, memory, malloc

In the [linux man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html),

> By default, Linux follows an optimistic memory allocation
> strategy.  This means that when malloc() returns non-NULL there
> is no guarantee that the memory really is available.

How is Linux able to lazily allocate memory?

My guess is that sbrk is called, Linux remembers the process ID and stores some kind of mapping to determine which virtual memory address it has allocated a physical address for. Where can I read to get more information on this?

Answer (score -1):

From https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html :

```
   Normally, malloc() allocates memory from the heap, and adjusts
   the size of the heap as required, using sbrk(2).  When allocating
   blocks of memory larger than MMAP_THRESHOLD bytes, the glibc
   malloc() implementation allocates the memory as a private
   anonymous mapping using mmap(2).
```

See [Why does calling mmap() with large size not fail?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9129004/why-does-calling-mmap-with-large-size-not-fail) .